# Odd duplicate symbols error

Tags: c++, debugging

For a school project, the class was asked to write a `String` class to mimic the STL `string` class.

I have all the code written, but the linker seems to be caught up on one of my operators.

There are three files, `String.h`, `String.cpp`, and `test2.cpp`

My `Makefile` looks like

```
CC=gcc
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS+=-Wall -Wextra
LDLIBS+=-lstdc++

all:test2

test2:test2.o String.o
test2.o:test2.cpp String.h
String.o:String.cpp String.h
```

`make` outputs the following:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra   -c -o test2.o test2.cpp
g++ -Wall -Wextra   -c -o String.o String.cpp
g++   test2.o String.o  -lstdc++ -o test2
ld: duplicate symbol operator==(String const&, char const*)in String.o and test2.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test2] Error 1
```

This is odd, since the only place I define `operator ==` is in `String.h`:

```
#ifndef MY_STRING_H
#define MY_STRING_H
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>

class String {
    //...
};

// ... operators ...

bool operator ==(const String& left, const char* right)
    { return left.compare_to(right)==0; }
bool operator ==(const char* left, const String& right)
    { return right.compare_to(left)==0; }
bool operator ==(const String& left, const String& right)
    { return left.compare_to(right)==0; }

// ... other comparison operators ...
#endif
```

`test2.cpp` only has a bare `main` method:

```
#include "String.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

}
```

So, if I only define `operator ==(const String&, const char*)` in one place, why does it say I have a duplicate symbol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You provided the *definitions* of the operators in the header file which gets included by both *String.cpp* and *test2.cpp*.
You should move the definitions into one source file and only provide *declarations* in the header file.

```
// in String.h:
bool operator==(const String& left, const char* right);

// in String.cpp:
bool operator ==(const String& left, const char* right) {
    return left.compare_to(right)==0; 
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, make the definitions in the header file inline.  The general rule is that any function definitions in a header file should be inline, and definitions in a source file should not be inline.